# Membership website from scratch

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership

I'm a total newbie for database-based website. I just learned designing website from zero but now I'm figuring out how to make a membership website locally (no Wordpress, no Joomla, etc).

My website is an online ordering site. Register to save my customer data in my database and he/she can make an order.

My customer could login back to edit their data (like address etc.) or make another order using the same information they save in my website database.

Where should I start first?

Are there any basic tutorials that I can use to get started with everything? What do i need? Visual Studio 2010? WAMP? IIS?

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET come with heaps of example programs that show you exactly how to do things like this?

Comment: See [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a detailed walkthough on user profiles and membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Note the paragraph:

> Have nothing? This button will install everything for you, including
>   Visual Studio 2012 & MVC 4.

You can use Visual Studio Express and try out the MVC scaffolding (template) provided. It gives a complete, working example including database access and membership. You can use all, some, or none of the code provided.

You can also following tutorials such as [this introduction](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3), and [this sample music store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1).

Comment: wow thx for the tuts link! I getting to get my sense in most everything :D

Answer (score -1):

If you use Visual Studio , you will be developing in ASP.NET with database as SQL Server.
If you use WAMP , you will developing using PHP with database as MySQL.

Since you mentioned you have STARTED learning ASP.NET , I suggest don't go with  Visual Studio straight away , the IDE may overwhelm you , atleast it did me.

Rather start with tutorial given at w3schools **[HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp)**.

For running the website the tutorial mentions to install a light weight software called **WebMatrix.**

The tutorial at w3schools covers forms and database connectivity which is what you required for a building website having registration, login , edit details etc facility.

Comment: omg thxx! I was clueless about WAMP as i read some forum saying i needed WAMP and no idea of it. i didnt know it was developing PHP, saving my time in my research :) thanks. i give it my try using webmatrix too.